# Get Fixed Width file row as single column in Azure Data Factory - Mapping data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a set of Fixed width files in ADLS.
I am reading the file with the following flow:

MetadataActivity --> ForEach.

Inside ForEach, I have a Mapping Data Flow with this source settings:

[image]

My projection looks like :

[image]

My expected projection is :

[image]

Please let me know what changes I have to do to get the  above projection. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried serval times to  reproduce the problem.

1.Have you set any value to the **Column delimiter** at the **Source dataset**?

[image]

2.In my source data, it contains the ',' as follows
[image]

3.ADF will divide this column into three columns automatically.
[image]

4.If so, you should select `No delimiter`.
[image]

5.After select `No delimiter`, there will be just one column.
[image]

---

**Additional**
My Wildcard is as follows:
[image]
I guess your source data contains any other delimiter?  Please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Can you please share me what you have given in Wildcard?

Comment: Yes. I add it to the answer at **Additional** part

Comment: Have you clicked **Reset schema** button and re import projection? It still have multiple columns?

Comment: I hope I found the problem. In the Source Dataset, I chose csv while importing schema. Now I have chosen * and imported the schema. I am getting one column. Triggering now. Lets see.

Comment: Yes Joseph. Issue resolved after changing the schema in source dataset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220843/discussion-between-madan-and-joseph-xu).

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after changing the schema in source dataset.

It was csv before:

[image]

Issue was fixed after change the schema to " From Files with "*""

[image]